# What does the following python code snippet do?

Tags: python

```
def reverse(text):
    final_string = ""
    count = len(text)
    while count > 0:
        final_string += text[len(text)-1]
        text = text[0:len(text)-1]
        count -= 1
    return final_string
```

This is the code snippet. I know it reverses the string "text" but can't seem to understand how it does so.

Comment: Which part is it, you can't understand?

Comment: It does so very inefficiently :(

Comment: It basically takes characters off of the end of `text` and places them at the end of `final_string`. But why don't you throw some `print`s in there and verify this yourself?

Comment: @JoeFrambach indeed, it looks like something directly mapped from c to python

Comment: `def reverse(text): return text[::-1]` :)

Comment: @shahkalpesh the part where text is being modified. cannot understand it.

Comment: @JoeFrambach dont care about efficiency presently.

Comment: This `text = text[0:len(text)-1]` -> reduces the text everytime by 1 less character from the right. i.e. if `text = "Prakhar"`, `text = text[0:len(text)-1]`makes it Prakha. The next iteration will make it Prakh.

Comment: The part about text being modified is known as splicing. Google it "Splicing python".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def reverse(text):
    final_string = "" 
    count = len(text) # sets the counter variable to the length of the string variable
    while count > 0: # starts a loop as long as our counter is higher than 0
        final_string += text[len(text)-1] #copies the last letter from text to final string
        text = text[0:len(text)-1] #removes the last letter from text
        count -= 1 #decrements the counter so we step backwards towards 0
    return final_string
```

Answer (score 3):

`final_string += text[len(text)-1` gets the last character of `text` and adds it to the end of `final_string`.

`text = text[0:len(text)-1]` removes the last character of `text`; basically it shortens `text` by the character that was just added to `final_string`.

`count -= 1` counts down to zero.  When zero is reached `text` is 0-length and `final_string` has all of the characters in `text` added to it.

Answer (score 1):

It repeatedly adds the last character from `text` to `final_text` and then shortens `text` until it should have no more characters.

Answer (score 0):

It takes an answer string,  finds the length of original text and places it in a variable count. It then uses this variable to places the string from reverse to front one character at a time while deleting the characters from the original string.

Much better solution would be

```
reverse_text = text[::-1]
```

That is all that is needed for reversing a string.